# Expression for the rank of a matrix

Tags: matrix-rank, pseudoinverse

According to the links [Rank and Trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29) and [Projection Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)), the rank of a matrix $X$ with entries in $\mathbb{R}$ can be computed by the equation

> $$\text{rank} (X) = \text{tr}\left(X (X^TX)^{+}X^T\right) \hspace{20 mm} (1)$$ where $(X^TX)^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse of $X^TX.$

I have tested by simulations that the rank of a matrix $X$ with entries in $\mathbb{C}$ can be computed by

> $$\text{rank} (X) = \text{tr}\left(X^+ X\right) \hspace{37 mm} (2)$$

Notice that $\text{tr}\left(X^+ X\right) = \text{tr}\left(XX^+\right)$ and equation $(1)$ can be obtained from $(2)$ if $X$ has full column rank, according to the link [Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse).

I want to answer the following questions:

> $(a)$ How to prove that equation $(2)$ always holds (or not)?
>
> $(b)$ How to derive equation $(1)$ from $(2)$ when $X$ is not full column rank?

I just need some hints. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the fact that every projection matrix $A$ satisfied $\operatorname{rank} A = \operatorname{tr} A$ ? Notice that your $X^+ X$ is a projection matrix, and its rank is that of $X$. This should give (2).

Comment: @darijgrinberg, In this case $\text{tr}(X^+X) = \text{rank}(X^+X)$. Maybe is it obvious, but I cannot see that  $\text{rank}(X^+X) = \text{rank}(X)$.

Comment: We have $X = X X^+ X$, thus $\operatorname{rank}X = \operatorname{rank}\left(X X^+ X\right) \leq \operatorname{rank} \left(X^+ X\right) \leq \operatorname{rank} X$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, Okay. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: By the way, do you see how (1) follows from (2) in general? (not just for $X$ of full column rank)

Comment: Yeah! Since $\text{tr}\left(X(X^TX)^+X^T\right) = \text{tr}\left((X^TX)(X^TX)^+\right)$ and using the fact that $\text{rank}(X^TX) = \text{rank}(X)$ and following your preceding explanation, the equation holds. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, exactly! (And this is why $X$ being real matters.)